# Find shift and rotation of image by comparing and finding location of maximum feature in image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection, cross-correlation

I am trying to solve two problems.

1. I have two same image one as it is and other as some rotation and shift in it. I tried using phase correlation for finding the shift on image and it works fine. But when there is rotation in image then because of that there is large pixel shift in corners of image and because of this I am getting wrong shifts by using phase correlation. I don't know how to find correct shift and rotation of image??
   I tried using `mellin transform` but I found its implementation too tough in GitHub can someone give me simple implementation of that in C++.
2. In repeating structure also I am getting wrong answer using phase correlation. Can someone tell how to find location of maximum feature of image so that I can just compare that location and find correct shift of image in repeating structure.

Thank you

Comment: The "standard" procedure is to find feature points in both images, match them using feature descriptors and from this compute the geometric transformation.

Comment: "fourier-mellin", interesting. I never thought about that *thoroughly*. fourier transform turns translation into phase which can be ignored, so focus on magnitudes. rotation shows as rotation in the spectrum, and scaling as (inverse) scaling, so log-polar transform of the spectrum to turn rotation/scaling into translations in the log-polar of the spectrum. -- this doesn't look too difficult. I see a bunch of recipes on methlab central. -- opencv comes with 2D FFT and log-polar warping. all the bits are there.